# Is it possible for the output SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I think this is not possible, but I need this result:

There are two tables:

`work_item(work_item_id, name)` 
with values`([529,DD],[539,ER])`

`work_item_party(work_item_id,party_type,party_name,country)`
with values`([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])`

Where

```
[1] = (529,applicant,mac,us)
[2] = (529,consignee,l-communication,a)
[3] = (529,end-user,u-a,a)
[4] = (539,applicant,dell,us)
[5] = (539,consignee,l-touch,b)
[6] = (539,end-user,u-b,b)
[7] = (539,end-user,c-b,b)
```

This is the output I need:

```
"work_item_id","name","applicant","consignee",end-user,"country"
(
[529,DD,mac,l-communication,u-a,a],
[539,ER,dell,l-touch,u-b,b],
[539,ER,dell,l-touch,c-b,b]
)
```

I can pull out data for each case where either party_type is applicant or consignee or end-user, but it is hard to combine them to yield the result as output above. Do you think it is possible. If yes, can you show me you query?

Comment: Show your query, what did you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/681f8/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE work_item(work_item_id, name) AS
          SELECT 529,'DD' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 539,'ER' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE work_item_party(work_item_id,party_type,party_name,country) AS
          SELECT 529,'applicant','mac','us' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 529,'consignee','l-communication','a' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 529,'end-user','u-a','a' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 539,'applicant','dell','us' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 539,'consignee','l-touch','b' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 539,'end-user','u-b','b' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 539,'end-user','c-b','b' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH applicant_consignees AS (
  SELECT p.work_item_id,
         i.name,
         MAX( CASE party_type WHEN 'applicant' THEN party_name END ) AS applicant,
         MAX( CASE party_type WHEN 'consignee' THEN party_name END ) AS consignee
  FROM   work_item i
         INNER JOIN
         work_item_party p
         ON ( i.work_item_id = p.work_item_id )
  WHERE  party_type IN ('applicant', 'consignee')
  GROUP BY p.work_item_id, i.name
),
end_users AS (
  SELECT work_item_id,
         party_name AS "end-user",
         country
  FROM   work_item_party
  WHERE  party_type = 'end-user'
)
SELECT a.*,
       e."end-user",
       e.country
FROM   applicant_consignees a
       INNER JOIN
       end_users e
       ON ( a.work_item_id = e.work_item_id )
ORDER BY a.work_item_id, name, country
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/681f8/11/0)**:

```
| WORK_ITEM_ID | NAME | APPLICANT |       CONSIGNEE | END-USER | COUNTRY |
|--------------|------|-----------|-----------------|----------|---------|
|          529 |   DD |       mac | l-communication |      u-a |       a |
|          539 |   ER |      dell |         l-touch |      u-b |       b |
|          539 |   ER |      dell |         l-touch |      c-b |       b |
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I got this can yield solution:

Comment: select t1.work_item_party,
  t1.party_name as applicant,
  t2.party_name as enduser,
  t3.party_name as enduser, 
  t1.country
from wi_party t1
left join wi_party t2 on t1.work_item_party = t2.work_item_party
left join wi_party t3 on t1.work_item_party = t3.work_item_party
  and t2.party_type = 'applicant'
where t1.party_type = 'consignee'
and t3.party_type = 'enduser'

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
Select A.work_item_id, A.name, B.party_name, C.party_name, D.party_name, D.Country
 From work_item as A
   left outer join work_item_party as B on A.work_item_id = B.work_item_id and B.party_type = 'applicant'
   left outer join work_item_party as C on A.work_item_id = C.work_item_id and C.party_type = 'consignee'
   left outer join work_item_party as D on A.work_item_id = D.work_item_id and D.party_type = 'end-user'
```

I hope you are looking for the country of end user... You can also use inner join, if you are sure that there will be atleast be 1 record per work_item_id per party_type in the Work_item_party table